# Changing Long.MIN_VALUE using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, static, final

I knew that there is a trick to change the value of a `static final` field using reflection and thought of trying it on `Long`

```
    Field field = Long.class.getField("MIN_VALUE");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, 2);
    System.out.println(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

But the above code does not even throw any exception neither does it change the value of `Long.MIN_VALUE`. Why is it so?

Comment: I've noticed a similar behavior before. It seems that Java caches primitive (and `String`) final values so changing them via reflection generally won't work.

Comment: (addendum to previous comment) You will find that if you access the field through reflection rather than directly it will hold the changed value rather than the old value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant primitive values are compiled directly into the using code. At runtime, the field is not accessed any more. Therefore, changing it afterwards does not have any effect on the using code.

The best reference I found is the following paragraph from section [13.4.9 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9):

```
If a field is a constant variable (§4.12.4), then deleting the keyword final or
changing its value will not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries by
causing them not to run, but they will not see any new value for the usage of
the field unless they are recompiled. This is true even if the usage itself is
not a compile-time constant expression (§15.28).
```